# fatal when unwrapping UIImage from ImagePicker to Firebase.Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiimagepickercontroller, firebase-storage

Trying to create an image stored in Firebase from UIImagePicker, throws a fatal upon receiving as ImageData is nil. How can the image picker return nil?

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)
        let imagePath = "\(uid)/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000)).jpg"
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        self.storageRef.child(imagePath)
            .putData(imageData!, metadata: metadata) { [weak self] (metadata, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error uploading: \(error)")
                    return
                }



    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the `imageData` is nil, and not something else?

Comment: @Sweeper I think so, because Firebase.Analytics shows the upload task is scheduled then aborted on unwrap, and nothing else in the putData arguments is optional.

Comment: Try using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` instead.

Comment: @Sweeper still no, also I tried casting the OriginalImage as! UIImage rather than as?. Where does the optional come from in the first place?

Comment: If you provide a metadata with content type and Firebase does not agree with you then it will give you a fatal error. Provide nil like this .putData(imageData!, metadata: nil) and Firebase will infer the type for you. If I am correct it will work and store as "application/octet-stream" in your Firebase storage.

Comment: Did this suggestion help?

Comment: @gwinyai Still don't think that works, I'm not sure it's getting to Firebase in the first place. I think .putData is failing before upload. Nothing has been added to Firebase storage, which works elsewhere in the project. When I ask to print the imageData it puts Optional(14360615 bytes). How does this unwrap to nil?

Comment: Oh I see then in that case can you simply just do this, guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) else { return } which will remove the optional. That might be the problem because there definitely seems to be an image.

Comment: @gwinyai Still no. This is definitely a problem with the imagepicker and .putData but when I print all the output from imagepicker I can see `<UIImage: 0x170297200> size {1932, 2576} orientation 3 scale 1.000000
610955 bytes` . Where can the optional data come from in the first place? (I also removed the optionals of all the possible variables with your method.

Comment: Could you remove this line, picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil) and put it right at the end of your imagePickerController method instead of at the beginning. It seems you are dismissing the picker too early and the image becomes nil as a result.

Comment: @gwinyai Thanks a lot, this worked, it got passed to octet-stream, and into the database.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked out. I have written the solution as an answer below. May I please ask if could confirm it as the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you remove this line,

```
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
```

and put it right at the end of your imagePickerController method instead of at the beginning. It seems you are dismissing the picker too early and the image becomes nil as a result.